# why do i keep getting "video system not initialized" my pygame game?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been following this [tutorial](https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/game-development-with-python/snake-pygame/tutorial-1/) and I have completed all the sections to it, however, I have been getting a traceback error like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects/Snake/Snake.py", line 207, in <module>
    main()
  File "PycharmProjects/Snake/Snake.py", line 192, in main
    s.move()
  File "PycharmProjects/Snake/Snake.py", line 57, in move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

The following is the code a few lines above and below the error. Line 199-207:

```
    for x in range(len(s.body)):
        if s.body[x].pos in list(map(lambda z: z.pos, s.body[x + 1:])):
            print('Score: ', len(s.body))
            message_box('Game Over!', 'Play again...')
            s.reset((10, 10))
            break


main()
```

Line 189-193:

```
while flag:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
    clock.tick(10)
    s.move()
    redrawwindow(win)
```

Line 54-60:

```
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for _ in keys:
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
```

It also has been running and the window is appearing but it isn't collecting the 'snack' as per how a Snake game should do. [Here's](https://github.com/rhm-99/Snake) the link to the GitHub repo if needed.

Comment: HAve you done `pygame.init()`?

Comment: @Torxed I've just added it but it doesn't seem to be fixing the error..

Comment: Since it's required to see the relevant code, I can't say why the error is still there. Update your code and we can check. Tried executing the code, it works for me.

Comment: @Torxed that's unusual, it may be a problem with the python version I have?

Comment: Doubt it, but just to be curious, what versions are you running (python + pygame). And could you run this game from a normal terminal (cmd.exe in windows for instance).

Comment: @Torxed running Python 3.8 and Pygame 1.9.6. I've run it from the terminal, however, there is now a traceback error for importing pygame.

Comment: That's because you installed pygame in a virtual environment (venv), something your IDE sets up for you. I strongly recommend you get familiar with the basic concepts of how python runs and how to execute things as these are crucial for understanding what is going on.

Comment: `pygame.quit()` will not quit your python process. It will uninitialize the pygame module. Once you call `pygame.quit()`, a lot of pygame functions won't work (until you call `pygame.init()` again. So, if you want to exit your game the hard way, call `exit()` instead of `pygame.quit()`, or immediatly after `pygame.quit()`.